# "Бон вояж" vs."Доброго пути"

Tags: выбор-слова, разница

What is the difference between **бон вояж** and **Доброго пути**?

My friend is going from city to city (about 10 hours far) I want to wish her a good wish for her journey. Which one is more common and understandable?

Comment: Do you understand that "бон вояж" is not Russian but the transcription of French "bon voyage"?

Comment: Yes. But I found it on translator... a lot of languages used to borrow phrases from other languages. A good example is  приятного аппетита that basically is semi borrowing of bon appetit (French).

Comment: @Influx ironically, French tend not to say bon appetit nowadays, also, the very fact that somebody borrowed this phrase does not mean that "bon voyage" also is widely adopted, it's not.

Answer (score 6):

Бон вояж is too 18th century. You'll be much better off with Счастли́вого пути́!

Answer (score 6):

`Bon voyage` (or `Бон вояж`, whatever) is a French phrase which the majority of native speakers will be very confused to hear - **it's just not used**. A big amount of people won't even understand you.

Stick to one from following list:

- доброго пути
- счастливого пути
- хорошей дороги
- хорошо вам добраться
- хорошо вам доехать / долететь

As of @Sergey-Slepov comment, it's very difficult to say whether it was adopted or not just because Russian aristocracy just was able easily to switch to French - and then "bon voyage" of course could be used.

In Russian though to my knowledge it was never widely adopted. 
Some times it was used with slightly different meaning like [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=dwSPBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA321&lpg=PA321&dq=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8A%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B6%D1%8A&source=bl&ots=2kRA1HipwE&sig=LNPmLRlZRSRhcvDk_A-bKn6WqQQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidneKkv_LUAhUGWRQKHdm9BAc4ChDoAQgyMAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8A-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B6%D1%8A&f=false):

[image]

In this context, "сделать бон вояж" is to make a nice trip.
[Here](https://books.google.de/books?id=IGhGAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA151&lpg=PA151&dq=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8A%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B6%D1%8A&source=bl&ots=fF098OxHAi&sig=KsLFPaNLc-J2A2PMBAk5IMjphBQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidneKkv_LUAhUGWRQKHdm9BAc4ChDoAQgoMAE#v=onepage&q=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8A%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B6%D1%8A&f=false)'s another example:

[image]

> Кто в аферисты, кто в пеструшки /
>   Пускается на авантаж /
>   Зато в самой Москве старушки /
>   Желают в Вятку бон-вояж (want to make a trip to Vyashka).

But even in this particular meaning (which, again, is not a wish of a nice trip but rather the trip itself) is obsolete and not used.

Comment: It's [`Vyatka`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirov,_Kirov_Oblast), not `Vyashka`. Bar is at top of the letter, so it's `т`.

Comment: "Скатертью дорога" еще, в принципе.